# insertar en base de datos mediante un array con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

hola muy buenas mi duda es la siguiente estoy haciendo un formulario donde la gente registrara una serie de daos en la base de datos in en esa serie de datos tenemos una serie de inputs donde el id es 1 2 3 asi sucesivo dependiendo de cuantos campos haya deseado insertar el usuario yo he creado una tabla donde tengo en los campos valor1 valor2 valor3 todos iguales excepto el numero que es lo unico que cambia . quisera saber como meter el array que recogo de la web en mysql  sabiendo cuantos valores tengo en el array la cosa es que en la base de datos solo quisera meter 2 de los 3 valores del array en la tabla y no el tercero como podria hacer la consulta con el insert para que sea dinamico y no tenga que poner todos los campos valor1 valor2 valor3 etc si que solo mediante el array poderlo ingresar

editado: creo que podria guardar toda una cadena de texto separada por comas en el insert y despues cuando la recoja hace un split por la coma creo que seria una buena solucion que piensan

muchas gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Te recomiendo guardarlo en formato JSON en lugar de un string separado por comas. Debes tomar en cuenta que el usuario podría insertar comas en los campos del formulario. También puedes crear una tabla donde almacenes los valores de cada campo y relacionarlo a la tabla del formulario.

Comment: @Roc no manejo jason e prodias decir mas o menos el camino , de todas formas si el usuario pone las comas se puede guardar de esa forma en la base de datos como un bloque de texto despues coger delimitar por comas y quitar la como

Comment: Si quieres usar JSON, puedes convertir un array a JSON con [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) y de JSON a array con [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @Rocko osea que lo que coja del input con coma y demas lo codifica a json guarde el string del json y lo decodifique despues al regresarlo y trabaje con el texto cierto

Comment: @rocko digo yo que json preservaria las comas que utilizaria como delimitaodr no

Comment: sería mucho mas simple manejar una columna JSON en tu base de datos y ahi guardar los registros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

En al formulario insertas todos las etiquetas input que necesites

```
<input type="text" name="campo[]" />
<input type="text" name="campo[]" />
<input type="text" name="campo[]" />
...
```

Nota como todos los `input` del mismo tipo tienen el mismo valor en el atributo `name` (**campo[]**). Eso significa que serán enviados como array.

Con PHP tomas el valor de los input

```
$POST['campo'];              // <- Array
json_encode($POST['campo']); // <- JSON String
```

Guardas el JSON string que devuelve json_encode en la columna correspondiente de tu base de datos.

Cuando hagas el select a la base de datos para obtener el formulario conviertes el JSON string a array

```
$row['campo'];                    // <- JSON String
json_decode($row['campo'], true); // <- Array
```

---

**Nota:** Creo que sería mejor crear una tabla con los valores de cada input y asociarlos a la tabla del formulario en lugar de usar JSON o un string separado por comas. Pero eso lo debes evaluar tú tomando en cuenta todos los detalles de tu proyecto.

Comment: eso iba a hacer pero me estaba rayando  y no sabia como guardar cada input en cada vammpo de la tabla  sin tener que meter todos y poner algunos nulos ya que en ocasiones no van a poner todos los datos dentro de valor 1 valor 2 valor 3 alomejor ponen valor 1 y valor 2 y no ponen el tercero es ahi donde me lio si pudieras explicarme como seria mas o menos te lo agradeceria muchisimo crees que la forma del json es mala , esto como se haria (Creo que sería mejor crear una tabla con los valores de cada input y asociarlos a la tabla del formulario )

Comment: De esta forma el JSON que contiene todos los valores de tus input lo guardarías en un solo campo de tu tabla.